# Email gets empty values

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I have created a web form form and configure email setting for that but it sends the empty values in the email.

Here's my form:
http://www.harvardstreet.org/request-appointment

Here's my form Configuration:
[image]

And Here's how it's looking in the email:

[image]

Help me, please!

Comment: Are you had print correct your field in webform ?

Comment: Hi @vinhdv, what did you mean by this? If you mean tokens in the template then it should display all values in [submission:values].